# Python: How can I use a String for a If-Statement?

Tags: python

In Python I have to build a (long) if statement dynamically.
How can I do this?

I tried the following test code to store the necessary if-statement within a string with the function "buildFilterCondition".
But this doesn´t work...

Any ideas? What is going wrong?
Thank you very much.

```
Input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
Filter = [4,7]
FilterCondition = ""

def buildFilterCondition():
    global FilterCondition
    for f in Filter:
        FilterCondition = FilterCondition + "(x==" + str(f) +") | "

    #remove the last "| " sign
    FilterCondition = FilterCondition[:-2]
    print("Current Filter: " + FilterCondition)



buildFilterCondition()
for x in Input:
    if( FilterCondition ):
        print(x)
```

With my Function buildFilterCondition() I want to reach the following situation, because the function generates the string "(x==4) | (x==7)", but this doesn´t work:

```
for x in Input:
    if( (x==4) | (x==7) ):
        print(x)
```

The output, the result should be 4,7 (--> filtered)

The background of my question actually had a different intention than to replace an if-statement.

I need a longer multiple condition to select specific columns of a pandas dataframe.

For example:

```
df2=df.loc[(df['Discount1'] == 1000) & (df['Discount2'] == 2000)]
```

I wanted to keep the column names and the values (1000, 2000) in 2 separate lists (or dictionary) to make my code a little more "generic".

```
colmnHeader = ["Discount1", "Discount2"]
filterValue = [1000, 2000]
```

To "filter" the data frame, I then only need to adjust the lists.

How do I now rewrite the call to the .loc method so that it works for iterating over the lists?

```
df2=df.loc[(df[colmHeader[0] == [filterValue[0]) & (df[colmHeader[1]] == filterValue[1])]
```

Unfortunately, my current attempt with the following code does not work because the panda-loc function has not to be called sequentially, but in parallel.

So I need ALL the conditions from the lists directly in the .loc call.

```
#FILTER
colmn = ["colmn1", "colmn2", "colmn3"]
cellContent = ["1000", "2000", "3000"]

# first make sure, the lists have the same size
if( len(colmn) == len(cellContent)):
    curIdx = 0
    for curColmnName in colmn:
        df_columns= df_columns.loc[df_columns [curColmnName]==cellContent[curIdx]]
        curIdx += 1
```

Thank you again!

Comment: don't use globals. pass `FilterCondition` as a parameter and then return the modified value. Like this `FilterCondition = buildFilterCondition(FilterCondition)`. Then your condition iterates x over input, but then your conditional just checks `FilterCondition` (which will not change over each iteration, since it's independent of `x`). What are you trying to do? can you post an example of the output you expect your code to generate for that particular input that you posted?

Comment: Rather than trying to use a string, you'd be better off using a class that can represent a simple bool expression.  You could then call a method of that class, passing it a dict (or namespace) of variable bindings, to evaluate it.  That would avoid the need for dynamic string parsing.

Comment: From you example it's not clear why you need to build up a filter conditions as a string. Can't you use `if x in filter` instead of `if( FilterCondition )`?

Comment: OT: I would recommend to use f-strings like this: `FilterCondition += f"(x=={f}) | "`

Comment: Moreover, turn `FilterCondition` into an empty list, update it with `FilterCondition.append(f"(x=={f})")`, and after the loop use `' | '.join(FilterCondition)`.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `in` operator

Because simple if better than complex.

```py
inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
value_filter = [4, 7]

for x in inputs:
    if x in value_filter:
        print(x, end=' ')
# 4 7
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use operator module

With the operator module, you can build a condition at runtime with a list of operator and values pairs to test the current value.

```py
import operator

inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

# This list can be dynamically changed if you need to
conditions = [
    (operator.ge, 4),  # value need to be greater or equal to 4
    (operator.lt, 7),  # value need to be lower than 7
]

for x in inputs:
    # all to apply a and operator on all condition, use any for or
    if all(condition(x, value) for condition, value in conditions):
        print(x, end=' ')

# 4 5 6
```